# Converting string with microseconds to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, iso8601

I get a string as input from an application that is supposed to be a date. For some asinine reason the developers of the application decided provide precision to the microsecond. Well, actually, to the tenth of a microsecond.

The string is in the format: `2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930000`

Before they changed this input format I was using the following to convert the date.

```
select DATEADD(dd, 30, @Date)
```

I know I could just do a substring on the input and lop off the last 4 characters, however, I'm wondering if there is some way that I can use `CONVERT` to just convert the date, or if SQL just doesn't support dates with this type of precision.

Comment: You can. Try using SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(23), 'string'));

Comment: same error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: I edited it, my bad. The answer below is the same

Comment: Please always tag with the *version* of SQL Server you're using. In many cases, this will dictate what solutions are available, or at least the best solutions available.

Comment: Very true, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930000', 101)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930000', 101)
```

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930000', 101)` (ie. to a DATETIME when precision is exceeded), however, fails. The *important* key to the puzzle is to convert to a DATETIME2, or DATE if the time is entirely thrown away.

Comment: Agreed!  Dates can be funny...(e.g. SELECT CAST('2014-08-15 23:59:59.995' AS DATETIME); SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-08-15 23:59:59.995');)

Comment: Could be, with this I'm sort of changing topics: in my environment, the SELECTs both return .997 as the MS portion of the time, even though it is .995.  If you CONVERT/CAST to a DATETIME2 however, it behaves as you would expect and accurately CONVERTs/CASTs

Comment: Ah, yeah. DATETIME doesn't have the same accuracy as it does precision.. sneaky thing. (Once I switched to DATETIME2 I've not looked back.)

Answer (score 3):

Whoops, the following assumes that a date *and* time are desired. Substituting in DATE for DATETIME2 will work, just as it does with CONVERT and the time component is simply dropped.

---

A CAST to DATETIME2 works (this is for SQL Server *2008 R2* - YMMV elsewhere),

```
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930001' AS DATETIME2) t;
```

as [DATETIME2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.105).aspx) has a maximum precision of 100ns, or 7 digits after the decimal.

Then it can be converted to a normal DATETIME (either [explicitly or implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)), although this loses precision,

```
select CAST(CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930001' AS DATETIME2) AS DATETIME) t;
```

However such lost of precision is not allowed directly in a CHAR -> DATETIME cast, and there are precision tolerances for the other casts.

```
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.293' AS DATETIME) t;         -- OK*
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930' AS DATETIME) t;        -- fail
-- although a cast to DATETIME2 is happy to lose some precision
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930001' AS DATETIME2) t;    -- OK, no loss
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.29300014' AS DATETIME2) t;   -- OK, loss
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.293000144' AS DATETIME2) t;  -- OK, loss
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930001444' AS DATETIME2) t; -- fail
-- and a cast to DATE works up to 8 digits after the decimal
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.29300014' AS DATE) t;        -- OK, date only
select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.293000144' AS DATE) t;       -- fail
```

*DATETIME has a precision of 3 decimal digits, but it does not have millisecond accuracy.

As far as I am aware, the same rules for CHAR -> DATETIME/DATETIME2 apply to COVERT and losing maximum precision still results in an error.

---

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard provides no limit to precision, but "the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties".

Comment: select CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.29300014' AS DATETIME2) t; actually works for me...what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @koppinjo Hmm, it appears it has some tolerances. Thanks for the note, I've updated my answer. I'm running against 2008R2.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST('2014-08-15T17:38:22.2930000' AS DATETIME2) 

RESULT:  2014-08-15 17:38:22.2930000
```

Now since it is a valid datetime value in sql server, you have access to all the datetime functions, like you have mentioned in your question you wanted to use `DATEADD()`

Datetime2 gives you more precision than simple datetime data type, Read more about DATETIME2 data type [`here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).